# Reasonable way to detect gyroscope directions in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, gyroscope, device-orientation

I've been trying to play around with deviceorientation and tried to do a simple "rotate phone - move image" script. I am controlling the image via the event alpha angle.

This angle is uniform on all devices, it goes from 0-360, both on iOS and android phones. I have tested my script on a whole bunch of phones and after some tweaking everywhere it works quite fine.

HOWEVER, on this specific version of Samsung "Galaxy S4 mini", when i turn the phone to the right, the alpha does not **decrease**, but **increase instead** instead. normally, when i move phones to the right (no matter if it's turned 90 or 270 degrees), it the alpha decreases. This happens both on native android browser and google chrome.

Now i could try to detect this specific model of samsung phone and flip signs, but i am afraid that this will be issue on much more devices on future.

What would be a good way to detect the whether alpha changes positively or negatively in respect to phone rotation?